# How to add single quotes around a list of columns names?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which has few columns. I got the name of columns by getting it as an array_agg and then array_to_string. Like below:

```
"hospitalaccountrecord,locationname,patientkey,inpatientadmitdatetime,readmission,no_null_days_btw_admissions,cohort_assignment,admit_mon_feb,admit_mon_mar,admit_mon_apr,admit_mon_may,admit_mon_june,admit_mon_july,admit_mon_aug,admit_mon_sep,admit_mon_oct,a (...)"
```

The code I used was this:

```
select array_to_string(array_agg(column_name::text), ',') 
from 
(
select column_name 
from 
information_schema.columns 
where table_schema='a' and
table_name = 'b'
 order by columns.ordinal_position
) as v;
```

What I am looking for is the same thing but each column name should be enclosed in ''. Like

```
'hospitalaccountrecord','locationname','patientkey'
```

and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Don't need two `SELECT`s, only

```
    select string_agg(''''|| your_column_name ||'''', ',')
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
select string_agg(quoted_column_name, ',') 
from 
(
select '''' || column_name || '''' as quoted_column_name
from 
information_schema.columns 
where table_schema='a' and
table_name = 'b'
 order by columns.ordinal_position
) as v;
```

Comment: `array_to_string(array_agg(quoted_column_name::text), ',')` can be replaced with `string_agg(quoted_column_name, ',')`

Comment: This is true (and simpler).